# in Xamarin/App how do I Secure Files on ASP.NET Restful Server in folders from other users and general public

Tags: asp.net, security, xamarin, server, directory

I have an APP using restful server.  I want to store PDF's, images, etc. in folders on my server. How can I make the folders private on server, yet allow App to access only certain folders depending on their app access.

I have different users in app and security/tokens established, etc. But if they upload an image for their avatar (and now PDF's), they get stored in folders on the server, and I just display with image source=https://blahblah.com/org1/images/user232.jpg.

How can I make that not accessible to outside (like just going to browser), yet make accessible to app if they have correct login privilege's for that organization/user? And then further extend that logic to more sensative PDF's, and other docs uploaded through app. I didn't want to store in SQL since then harder to use simple image display tools and I already have upload and media managers using folders structures.

I can see how to secure if logging onto server through browser (credentials), but can't see how you connect App with that security level and maintain it for the session.

Comment: Don't store the files in a folder that's publicly accessible. Implement a handler or action method that checks user's access, and if they're allowed it retrieves the files from storage and writes it to the response.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers. Most of the work was done on the restful (ASP.NET) side.   I first tried using authorization/Authentication in web.config and having Allow and deny.  This allowed a redirect of a user to a login page; however, it didn't do it if they entered an image exactly correct on website.

Found HTTPHandlers (adding in webconfig ) where I could write code that would be executed once the user entered the specific Image address xyz/abc/image.png.  I found this a bit feeling like a hack.

So lastly modified my

```
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "staticFileRoute",
      url: "publicstor/{*file}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HandleStatic" }
```

And add a function like this to home controller.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public ActionResult HandleStatic(string file)
{
    if (Session["OrgId"] == null) //todo  need to add full security check.  
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
    else  //Either coming from app or coming from web interface
    {
        string mimeType = MimeInfo.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(file));

        return File(file, mimeType);
    }
}
```

The final bit is on the Xamarin side to now pass security when getting an image.  Since just a simple Xamarin.Forms.Image doesn't have a way to pass login info or tokens/authentication I used
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/145575/image-from-url-needing-auth
And established an appwide webclient that logged in generally once forcing my restful to go through security validation, then just accessed the images/documents through out my app from that webclient.  So far so good.  Hopefully there are no holes.

This gives the gist to a future reader.